# Using ng-repeat to repeat the same div with different id and ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How would I use ng-repeat to repeat multiple divs with this structure (where neighborhood will be different for every div, but the rest will be the same)?

```
<div id="neighborhood" ng-controller="WeatherController" ng-init="init('neighborhood')">
  <h1>It's currently {{weather}}</h1>
  <p>Sunny: {{sunny}}</p>
  <p>Foggy: {{foggy}}</p>
  <input type="button" value="Sunny" ng-click="sunny = sunny + 1"/>
  <input type="button" value="Foggy" ng-click="foggy = foggy + 1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean under `where neighborhood will be different for every div`?

Comment: @MaximShoustin each div will have a different id and a different ng-init value, which will be the name of a different neighborhood. For example: <div id="chinatown" ng-init="init('chinatown')"></div>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use interpolation to populate the `id` and call init with AngularJS's model

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="WeatherController" >
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        <div id="{{item.id}}" ng-init="init(item.value)">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function WeatherController($scope) {
    $scope.init = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    }

    $scope.data = [{
        id: 'neighborhood',
        value: 'neighborhood'
    }, {
        id: 'neighborhood1',
        value: 'neighborhood1'
    }]
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9VEEh/)**</kbd>